# generate a hyperlink in sheet linking to matched data found in a different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have two different sheets in a workbook with data, all of this data is organized by Site ID's. What I want to do is use these site ID's to create a hyperlink in one of the data sheets that when clicked takes the user to the corresponding Site ID in the other sheet. The sheet name where I want to write the hyperlinks to is called "Report_Manual" and I want to write hyperlinks down every row down the first column. The sheet that I am hyperlinking to is called "Data".  The premise Ids are located in column C for sheet "Report_Manual" and column K in sheet "Data". Below is an a ttempt of what I was trying to generate in excel for a single cell formula however the issue I ran into for this formula is that the Premise ID's in sheet "data" are variant data type while the Premise ID's in sheet "Report Manual" are integer data type. This makes even a simple formula like the one below not get any matches as the data types being matched aren't the same.

=HYPERLINK("#"&CELL("address",INDEX(Data!K3:K580001,MATCH(C3,Data!K3:K580001,0))),C3)

If anyone has any idea of a macro to solve this issue that would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If the IDs in "Data" are text, try changing your match lookup value to text:

```
=HYPERLINK("#"&CELL("address",INDEX(Data!K3:K580001,MATCH(TEXT(C3,0),Data!K3:K580001,0))),C3)
```